# why is shell (new terminal, new tmux panes/windows) slow to load?

Tags: shell, zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh, konsole

When I open a new terminal it takes a couple seconds for the shell to load, when I open a new pane or window in tmux it might even take a second longer.  The delay is about 3 seconds.

I'm using zsh with oh-my-zsh and the ohmyzsh plugins: git, vi-mode, history-substring-search.

My path looks like:

> /home/alec/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin:/home/alec/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/alec/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/alec/code/bin

Previously I had wondered if having a git repo on the path would be problematic.  The final location in that path `~/code/bin` used to be `~/bin` and there was the `.git` database inside it.  Now the `.git` directory is in `~/code` (which seems to me like it would prevent the shell from looking through it for executables) but this hasn't delivered any performance improvements.

I don't know any other guess-and-check possibilities, or any logical troubleshooting procedures to perform/investigate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Never used Zsh before, but since it's a shell and that sounds like a similar problem that you can have on bash...I'm guessing it might be either your zsh config or the plugins/extension you installed for Zsh which slow things down. (you could try with/without them and see the difference in speed to make sure)

Comment: disabling the plugins (including in "core" ohmyzsh) doesn't seem to deliver any performance improvement

Comment: what about the zsh config file? does using a smaller one/default one change anything?

Comment: You could run `PS4='%D{%T.%3.} %N:%i> ' script -c 'exec zsh --login -o xtrace'`, exit, and then look into the `typescript` file where all the time is spent.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas where would i find that typescript file?

Comment: In the current working directory where you started the `script` command from. See `man script`

Comment: `PS4='%D{%T.%3.} %N:%i> ' script -c 'exec zsh --login -o xtrace'` gives me more than 11,000 lines.... that seems a bit unmanageable....

Comment: You are using oh-my-zsh  - depending on what OMZ plugins you use, this can make the prompt take several seconds (or even longer) to appear (sometimes just the shell's initial prompt, sometimes every time the prompt is printed...i.e. after every single command you enter).   Fancy prompts have a cost, and the fancier the prompt, the bigger the cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `set -x` to the top and `set +x` to the bottom of `~.zshrc` to get a lot of output about what's being run during shell startup.  (It's helpful to keep that file open in a separate window/terminal/editor during the whole debug process)

It can be hard to know what's proper and what's problematic among all that output... but if you notice something that you recognize, that's a good place to start.  In my case there were many lines about `nvm`, the "node version manager".  Disabling the `nvm` lines in my `.zshrc` file eliminates two seconds from the shell startup!

To use `nvm` without the performance burden, https://www.ioannispoulakas.com/2020/02/22/how-to-speed-up-shell-load-while-using-nvm/ suggests a couple possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you! This allowed me to see that my problem was that I had a call to a service that normally worked but today was hanging.